# Json Parsing and display data in the tablelayout

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to parse json and display it into table layout without taking its keys. i want key as table header and attaching values to corresponding keys.
OUTPUT like this:

|**id**| **name**| **gender** |  **latitude**    |        **longitude**|

---

1   | Julie    |female |  37.33774833333334  |  -121.88670166666667

---

2   | Johnny  | male  |   37.336453     |       -121.884985

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TableLayout table;
String arr=null;
String value=null;
private final static String JSON_DATA =
        "{"
                + "  \"gdata\": ["
                + "    {"
                + "      \"id\": \"1\","
                + "      \"name\": \"Julie\","
                + "      \"gender\" : \"female\","
                + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\","
                + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""
                + "    },"
                + "    {"
                + "      \"id\": \"2\","
                + "      \"name\": \"Johnny\","
                + "      \"gender\" : \"male\","
                + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\","
                + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""
                + "    }"
                + "  ]"
                + "}";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

    try{

        TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(JSON_DATA);          


        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
             JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             arr = object.names().getString(i).toString();
            //Log.e("arr" +i, arr);
            value = object.getString(arr);
            //Log.e("value"+i,value);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));               
            tv.setText(arr);

            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv1.setText(value);
            row.addView(tv);
            row.addView(tv1);


        }
        table.addView(row);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_weight="0.49">
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i get only some values and these values are not in correct table format.

Comment: this maybe helpful http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/26/show-data-in-columns-in-a-tableview-dynamically-in-android/

Comment: Tku for your sugesstion.  i will try.